# White whale metaphor

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, metaphors

I’m translating an english book in my native language and here is a metaphor I’ve never heard ; the sentence is :

My personal **white whale**, author Neil gaiman .

What does white whale mean here ?

Comment: That is not a sentence. Also did you try a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

This is a reference to [Moby Dick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby_Dick_(whale)).  It refers to something that someone is obsessed with finding (but will probably never manage to do so) - the potentially mythical object of an endless, life-long quest.  See [here](https://whitney.org/whitneystories/mobydickmarathon) for more examples.

Comment: Thank you alot :)